# How to validate CSV headers using Univocity routines?

Tags: java, csv, parsing, univocity

Im using Univocity CSV parser with routines when I iterate over Java beans. Is there a way to validate CSV header? When I edit the CSV and add invalid header, it just insert into given bean null without any error.

**Model class:**

```
public class Customer {

@Format(formats ="yyyy-MM-dd")
@Parsed(field="C_DAY")
private Date day;

@Parsed(field="C_ID")
private Long id;

@Parsed(field="C_TYPE")
private String type;

@Format(formats ="yyyy-MM-dd")
@Parsed(field="C_ORIGIN_DATE")
private Date originDate;

@Format(formats ="yyyy-MM-dd")
@Parsed(field="C_REL_DATE")
private Date relDate;

@Parsed(field="C_LEGAL_ID")
private String legalId;

@Parsed(field="C_NAME")
private String name;}
```

**Parser:**

```
    @Autowired
private CustomerDAO dao;

public void parse(File file) throws IOException, SQLException, CustomerValidationException, ParseException {
    CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
    parserSettings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
    parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(false);
    CsvRoutines routines = new CsvRoutines(parserSettings);
    List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
    java.util.Date stamp = getTimestamp(file);
    dao.checkTimestampDate(stamp);


    for (Customer customer : routines.iterate(Customer.class, file, "UTF-8")) {
        validateFileDateWithFileName(stamp, customer.getDay());
        validateCustomer(customer);
        customers.add(customer);
    }
    dao.save(customers);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Author of the library here. The `BeanListProcessor` has a `strictHeaderValidationEnabled` property you can set to `true` to ensure all headers in your class exist in the input.

You just can't use the `CsvRoutines` in that case as that class implements convenience methods that use their own internal row processors, so yours will be ignored. Try this code:

```
    CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
    parserSettings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");

    final List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
    final java.util.Date stamp = getTimestamp(file);
    dao.checkTimestampDate(stamp);

    parserSettings.setProcessor(new BeanProcessor<Customer>() {
        @Override
        public void beanProcessed(Customer customer, ParsingContext context) {
            validateFileDateWithFileName(stamp, customer.getDay());
            validateCustomer(customer);
            customers.add(customer);
        }
    });

    new CsvParser(parserSettings).parse(file, "UTF-8");

    dao.save(customers);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Based on answer by Jeronimo Backes.

In case you have `@Header` annotation on the bean or know the exact headers but still need `setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true)`:

```
public <T> List<T> parse(File file, Class<T> beanType, char delimiter, Charset charset) {
    String[] headers = beanType.getDeclaredAnnotation(Headers.class).sequence(); // or other source

    CsvParserSettings parserSettings = Csv.parseRfc4180(); // or some other
    parserSettings.detectFormatAutomatically(delimiter);
    parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

    // initialize new processor (stateful, should not be reused! See implementation of parseAll)
    BeanListProcessor<T> processor= new BeanListProcessor<>();
    processor.setStrictHeaderValidationEnabled(true);
    parserSettings.setProcessor(processor);

    CsvParser csvParser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);

    csvParser.parse(file, charset);

    // header validation
    String[] headersParsed = processor.getHeaders();
    if (!Arrays.equals(headers, headersParsed)) {
        String message = String.format("Header validation failed. Expected: %s, but was: %s",
            Arrays.toString(headers), Arrays.toString(headersParsed));
        throw new DataProcessingException(message);
    }

    return beanListProcessor.getBeans();
}
```